# Run NUnit test cases of ASP .Net core application using VS Code

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, debugging, visual-studio-code, nunit

I have created the ASP .Net core project and i can able to run & debug that using visual studio code. But when i try to run the unit test cases in visual studio code, I could able to run the test cases by **dotnet run** command but i could not able to find a way to debug it using VS Code. I would like know about debugging the Nunit test cases of ASP.Net core projects using VS Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that using the CodeLens feature. Make sure you've installed the C# extension on your VS Code instance. Refer to [this](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/2458) link for more information.

You also need to make sure if you included required packages corresponding to unit testing like "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk", "NUnit3TestAdapter". You can find more about it [here](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/getting-started/dotnet-core-and-dotnet-standard.html).